# How to remove single element form child collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm new with MongoDB and
I have a data collection of mongodb like this [image]

I just want to remove child note from the rows if name is History and child note's name is I hate war.
I try to

```
db.rows.remove({ name: 'History', "notes.note": 'I hate war'});
or
db.rows.remove({name:'History', notes:{note:'I hate war'}});
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic CRUD operations `find`, `update`, `insert`, and `remove` operate on documents that are members of the collection - the top level documents, not the subdocuments. You need to use query operators to act on subdocuments:

```
db.rows.update({ "name" : "History" }, { "$pull" : { "notes" : { "note" : "I hate war" } } })
```

Read more in the docs on [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).